# Not able to kill process by "kill -9 <PID>"

Tags: process, kill

I want to kill process, which related to rsync.

By entering `ps axu | grep -i lsyncd`, I receive information about one process:

```
andrej   10690  0.0  0.0  15984  1148 pts/1    S+   16:52   0:00 grep --color=auto -i lsyncd
```

But when I'm trying to kill it, by using `sudo kill -9 10690` I receive:

```
 kill: (10690): There is no such process
```

Comment: This process is your `grep`. It already finished it's job ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to kill the command you are running.

The `10690` is a `grep` process. At the moment you are trying to kill it, it has been finished already.

Comment: Related: [How can I prevent 'grep' from showing up in ps results?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74185)

Answer (score 0):

Read `man pgrep` and use

```
pgrep lsyncd
pkill -9 lsyncd
```

You may have to preface `pkill` with `sudo`, if you don't own the process.